# Silverstripe Unit Tests modify live database (postgres module)

Tags: php, silverstripe

I have a site that was version 3.1.12 and using postgres module version 0.92.

I just upgraded everything to 3.5.3 and 1.2 respectively. All is well except some odd behaviour from my existing and unchanged unit tests. Seems to happen when the tests create objects programatically, like so:

```
$page=new Page();
$page->Title='Read only success';
$page->write();
```

On 3.1 and 0.92, the test would run and then return a success. Doing the above work in a tmp database.

After the upgrade the same test, without any modification, runs and returns a success. Only this time, the work is done in the current live database. In the above case, there is a new draft page in my admin site tree.

Anyone seen this before? I've exhausted my hunt for answers and ability to track what exactly is causing this ver dangerous behaviour.

Comment: Unless you test specific Postgres functionality I'd suggest to use in memory sqlite to speed up testing, see http://www.silverstrip.es/blog/how-to-speed-up-unit-tests-using-sqlite/

Comment: Thanks for the link. Looks interesting!

Comment: I'd actually disagree about the use of an alternate RDBMS. If you have a Postgres-backed application, and your application relies on a DB being present (Which SilverStripe does), then depending on the nature of test being run (integration / behaviour / unit) you should be testing a postgres-backed application, not an SQLite backed application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't use a fixture file for your test, you need to ensure you tell SapphireTest to use a test database:

```
protected $usesDatabase = true;
```

Otherwise creating DataObjects like that will write directly to your main database.

If you're using a fixture file this is implied anyway, so is only necessary when you're not.

[Here's the doc block, for reference](https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-framework/blob/3.5/dev/SapphireTest.php#L39-L44).

Comment: Thanks! That worked. Although I find it highly dangerous for it to be possible for a unit test to make any changes to the main DB. An uninitiated developer could easily write a test not aware that using this flag or a fixture could result in live changes. This was atomic in 3.1. I wonder what the intention was that change.

Comment: I entirely agree with you and think that the default should be "true" unless otherwise disabled rather than the current behaviour. You'd be more than welcome to create an RFC on the framework suggesting that!

Comment: Will do. I think this actually means the postgres module tests are currently broken. As it creates pages programatically without this option. https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-postgresql/blob/master/tests/PostgreSQLDatabaseTest.php#L20-L22. This test effectively adds pages to the current sitetree.

Comment: @Aaryn yes, true :) pull request would be ideal

Comment: I guess that settings was for "speeding up" tests (generating fixtures takes a long time) and devs didn't suppose to run tests in a live environment. That's what dev / testing environments are for.

Comment: @wmk Oh I agree. I wouldn't run tests on a live or staging site either. But this change also has repercussions for dev and testing environments. On top of that, it's actually possible that it will lead to false positive tests, unpredictable results, or simply confusion for developers who don't know this (very hidden) caveat. Few would expect this. And I can't see any possible reason why a unit test would ever need to write to the main DB. What a test does is simply for the lifetime of that test. It's the very nature of unit tests. Might be a use case for functional tests however.